# How to fetch N documents per-group after a group query in mongoengine?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

If I have a mongoengine collection with fields:

```
node_id = fields.StringField(max_length=255)
message = fields.StringField(max_length=255)
```

How can I group by `node_id` and get max. 5 documents per `node_id`?

For example:
If the documents in DB are:

[image: Sample documents stored in DB]

Then, after grouping by node_id and fetching only 5 documents per group, the expected output should be something like this:

[image: expected output with max. 5 documents per group]

From the documentation and some blogs, I was able to come up with the following query which gives only 1 document per group:

```
Model.objects.aggregate({"$group": {"_id": "$node_id", "count": {"$sum": 1}, "sentence":{"$first": "$message"}}})
```

But I am not able to figure out what should be the ideal approach to get maximum N documents per group?

Comment: what are you calling "records"? Documents?

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect terms. I get confused with the terms used in different Databases and within the company. Fixed the term to reflect "documents" instead of "records.

Comment: Alright, let me know if this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.objects.aggregate([{ 
[
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$node_id",
            "count" : {
                "$sum" : 1
            },
            "sentence" : {
                "$push" : "$message"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields" : {
            "sentence" : {
                "$slice" : [
                    "$sentence",
                    {
                        "$cond" : [
                            {
                                "$gt" : [
                                    "$count",
                                    5
                                ]
                            },
                            5, 
                            "$count"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]])
```

1. `$Group` documents by `node_id`
2. `$addFields` selects

   - 5 items if arr larger than 5
   - all items if arr smaller than 5